# Transfer iPhone to new computer: will I lose sensitive app data?

Tags: iphone, transfer

I currently use a Windows PC to manage the music and apps etc. on my iPhone 4 manually. I know, Windows but I need it for my university course.

I want to transfer the manual management of my iPhone to my Toshiba laptop for ease of remote access etc. I understand that in order to do so I must first erase the data on my iPhone and then use only the music data present on my laptop. I realise you can change iTunes settings to stop these devices syncing automatically, but I'm not interested in simply charging my iPhone from the laptop, I need to update it and manage music etc. 
My problem is the large number of (mostly medical) apps which were a pain in the ass to get on to my iPhone originally, due to specific permission being required to use the app, with a serial code amongst other things being required. I don't know if there is a term for these more complex apps, but I have a few of them and it would be a nightmare to lose them. I would sacrifice the ease of access of using my laptop to manage my iPhone in order to keep them.

My question: Is there any way to use my laptop computer to manage the music etc. on my iPhone without losing my apps?
I have authorized the laptop already, will my apps be retained and transferred easily from this new computer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy your iTunes folder from your old PC to your new PC
2. Authorise your new PC
3. Connect your iPhone

It should work like that, no need to mess around with erasing data.

Comment: Brilliant. Sounds almost too simple, I didn't know anything iPhone related could be solved in three steps.
Literally take the whole iTunes folder from Program files and copy it? Do I need to paste it somewhere in particular? Or just over the old iTunes folder?
Cheers

Comment: Do not copy the iTunes folder in Program Files. Copy the iTunes folder in "Music", or wherever your iTunes music and profile is stored.

Comment: Back everything up, first

Answer (score 0):

Use iTunes to backup your iPhone on your computer. Every time you connect your iphone to iTunes, it prompts you to backup. Compared with iCloud backup, iTunes backup is recommended. iTunes can back up your settings, Messages, Camera Roll, documents, saved games, and other data. Even there are some errors with your iPhone, you can restore the lost files from iTunes backup.

Remember, backin up your iPhone through iTunes regularly is really brilliant. Because of iPhone file loss happens frequently.